# React Native on goBack from SPECIFIC screen call a function refresh

Tags: react-native

I found similar questions but none answered it the way I need.

I use react navigation. I have two screens, HomeScreen and PostScreen. When I create a post in PostScreen I use

```
this.props.navigation.goBack()
```

and successfully go back to home screen, however inside HomeScreen I have a certain function called `refresh()` and I would love for that function to be called upon using goBack from PostScreen. Solutions on similar questions show how to refresh screen ,from goBack but anytime coming from ANY screen by using stuff like `onWillFocus()` or some listeners, but I want this behaviour to only be for specific screen. I guess I need to pass some stuff don't I? I use class components btw.

SO BASICALLY I NEED:
onWillFocus { this.refresh() IF I CAME FROM POSTSCREEN and not if I came from anywhere}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could navigate back sending one parameter to the `Home` screen in order to know when you should call the `refresh()` in `onWillFocus()`. Like this `navigation.navigate('Home", {refresh: true})`

Comment: i use different acc but its me. thats the way i tried before as well. But i keep getting error In Home screen when i try to call this refresh parametar im sending. I think your code is good for PostScreen, but how to receive this correctly in HomeScreen?  this is what im using:        
          `<NavigationEvents
            onWillFocus={() => {
          
              if (this.props.navigation.state.params.refresh) {
                this.onRefresh();
              }
            }}
          />`      when i go back to HomeScreen from somewhere else its saying its undefinied

Comment: Ok, I understand, did you try to put the condition like this: `if (this.props.navigation && this.props.navigation.state && this.props.navigation.state.params && this.props.navigation.state.params.refresh)` ?

Comment: I tried this and now i dont get error but now it refreshes from anywhere I come and not just exactly from PostScreen :( cant it somehow be that I use if(this.props.navigation.state.params.refresh){ } but only if it exists aka only if im coming from PostScreen damn:(

Comment: This is happening because you never set the refresh param to false and therefore it remains true. What you should do is to set the refresh param to false right after you call the refresh function

Comment: Thank u so much!!! what u mentioned now fully works:                                                             
     `<NavigationEvents
            onWillFocus={() => {
              if (
                this.props.navigation &&
                this.props.navigation.state &&
                this.props.navigation.state.params &&
                this.props.navigation.state.params.refresh
              ) {
                this.onRefresh();
                this.props.navigation.state.params.refresh = false;
              }
            }}
          />`